# How to access the swfcontrols from one mxml to other mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Hai i have SwfControl in page1.mxml,i need to hide and show that control...In page1 i hide that control and page 2 i need to show that control how to do?

Note page1.mxml is **main page**

page1.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:WindowsControl xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
                      xmlns:local="*"
                      height="100%" width="100%"
                      backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                      backgroundAlpha="0">
    <mx:HBox x="11" y="167" horizontalGap="0">
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:SWFLoader id="loader" source="loading.swf" visible="false"/>
</local:WindowsControl>
```

i need to **hide** the  **SWFloader** in page1.mxml  and **show** the  **SWFloader** in page2.mxml

page2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns="*" creationComplete="init()" width="164" height="150" cornerRadius="3">
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import flash.media.Microphone;
                import flash.media.Video;
              public function init():void
                {
                    loader.visible=true;
                }
               ]]>
        </mx:Script>
        <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" backgroundColor="#000000" >
            <VideoContainer id="vids" opaqueBackground="true" width="160" height="120" />
             </mx:VBox>
             </mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: I think you should Google for "Flex access properties of one component in another" There are plenty of answers out there and I believe that is the solution you need.  Here is one answer I gave:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847461/what-is-flex-good-practice-to-change-another-components-state

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?298578-Accesing-mxml-components-from-AS-class-(flex-3) am searching this link and i applied this one but i have error in VideoContainer class

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is by dispatching events to parent container of page1 and page2.
The parent container will relay the message/action to the target page. Your event will contain info of what is supposed to happen.